# Unity missing namespace

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

A couple hours ago I was trying to compile my game and it didn't work. In the console this error came up:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what that means or what is wrong with the compiler. The build always fails after 7 seconds, every time. I've tried to compile it 2 times with no success. Its only this project that is giving me some trouble I don't know if I should change the way it compiles or if there is a part of my code that is wrong. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Please post the errors further above in the console ... The ones you posted here are just the very last ones stating **that** there were errors but not **why/where** exactly. Without you providing the **actual** errors giving a proper answer is impossible

Comment: Change the Player settings Build system from Gradle to Internal
or Delete the "plugins" folder from the "Assets" folder of the project or
Check "use legacy SDK tools" under Player settings and Publishing settings

Comment: heres everything I see when I try to build locally (windows x86): https://imgur.com/a/mz8j8Vc and https://imgur.com/a/x9HZmjT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now that you added the actual errors:

What you get are missing namespaces for `UnityEditorInternal`

> The type or namespace name 'UnityEditorInternal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This happens for your scripts `CameraFollow.cs`, `PlayerSword.cs`, `HealthRenderer.cs`, `LevelData.cs`, `MovingZomby.cs`, `Player.cs`, ... without seeing these it is impossible to give a specific detailed answer.

But what I can say is: The entire `UnityEditor` and `UnityEditorInternal` namespaces are completely stripped of in a build since they only exist within the UnityEditor itself!

### You can not use anything from it in a build/your final application!

If your runtime code depends on it ... you have to search for another solution, I'm afraid ;)

Usually, however, these are only used for [Custom Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) scripting.

Make sure the according code blocks are either only in files placed in folders called `Editor` (these are also stripped of during the build process) or use [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) and wrap the using statements as well as anything using the namespaces in [`#if` pre-processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditorInternal;
#endif

...

#if UNITY_EDITOR
// anything using that namspace
#endif
```